# WCF Hosting - deciding factors

Tags: wcf, web-services, windows-services, soa

I did google this . Could not find any concrete answer.
What are the deciding factors(in general no specific scenarios) would i have  to look at to host WCF service.

```
1. IIS
2. Windows Service
3. WAS
4. Self Hosting
```

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: this is in general with out having any

Comment: Your business requirements absolutely dictate how you should host the service. If you have no business requirements, then you might as well roll a die to decide.

Comment: assume this is an interview question .You will have deciding factor some are common and some are unique. I am really surprised to see without a scenario no factors

Comment: Huh? OK, I'll take the bait. If IIS is available on the server, use that. If WAS is available on the server, use that. Otherwise use a Windows Service. This is a trick question; you have a totally free choice between all 4 methods unless some external factor not under your control reduces your choices.

Answer (score 2):

Benefits of self-hosting:

- supports all protocols
- supports any service address (no need for a `.svc` file that shows up in the service address)
- no "surprises" when IIS recycles app pools unexpectedly
- more control over life-time of service and how to set it up etc.

Downsides:

- potentially a tad more complex to get up and running

---

Benefits of hosting in IIS:

- simpler to set up and easier to get running

Downsides of IIS:

- IIS 6 (Win Server 2003) doesn't support anything except HTTP
- depends on `.svc` file that shows up in the service address
- location of that `*.svc` file determines much of the service address

Personally, for anything beyond a demo app, I would choose self-hosting; once you've done it once or twice, it's not a problem any more, and it just gives you more flexibility and more control over the whole WCF service hosting.